# how to run html on python openshift server

Tags: openshift

I have an OpenShift server running python. However when I call php via SSL the php interpreter starts running. It suggests that there might be a way to run php as well. However, HTML if fair enough for me. Now, I do not know how to be able to reach html files on my server as when I am trying I always get `404 not found`. I've read about a solution of placing a `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I am not exactly sure where to place this file but placing in the folder of the .html file still not helps.

Could you please help me how I can make .html files reachable at an OpenShift server running Python? How about php?

Comment: The easiest way to handle html content is using the php-5.3 cartridge.  You can treat your repo/php/ dir as your web root.  For python, it all depends on the framework you're using so it's much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Put the .html file in your app-root/repo/wsgi/static folder (or in that folder in your git repository).  if you want it to be displayed like app-domain.rhcloud.com/file.html, you will have to use a .htaccess file in your wsgi folder that rewrites file.html to static/file.html